# TYPES keyword in ABAP

Tags: abap

Please tell me what does this two statement exactly do? Why the `TYPES:` declaration is used? Normally we will use

```
DATA: lv_name(30) type c. "for data declaration. 

TYPES: rsr_format(1) TYPE c. "what it refers to.
```

And for declaring a structure in ABAP, will do like this:

```
types: begin of ztudent,
         name(10) type c,
         age(2) type n,
       end of zstudent.
```

Comment: These are basic pieces of information which can be found in any introduction to ABAP.

Answer (score 3):

[TYPES defines a data type](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/fc/eb30ea358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm), [DATA declares a variable](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/fc/eb3034358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm). Please do use the excellent online-documentation since it also answers your question regarding structures with lots of examples.

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting at is a very basic programming concept. I'm responding because it may even be too basic to be described in ABAP documentation. We specify types for data for the same reasons we specify job titles for people. When someone asks you what you do for a living, it's easier to say "I'm a programmer" than it is to say "I input instructions coded in the ABAP language into a mainframe so that they can be interpreted and carried out by a processor...".

From the machine's perspective, a TYPE statement describes how the data should be stored in memory and how it should be interpreted (TYPE c LENGTH 30 = 60 bytes of unicode characters; TYPE i = 4 an integer stored in 4 bytes). A DATA statement reserves a specific location in memory for that structure.

```
TYPES: ty_number TYPE i. " Defines a 4-byte integer space
DATA: l_number TYPE ty_number. " Reserves 4 bytes in memory, and tells the system that data stored in those 4 bytes should be interpreted as an integer.
```